# Prove or disprove the inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $d,\ a,\ x,\ b,\ y $ be integers. $d$ divides $a$ and $b$.

The question is:  Assume $ax + by \gt 0$. Prove or disprove : $d \le ax + by $

I know that $d | ax+by$, but I can't figure out the proof for why $d$ would be $\le ax+by$.

Comment: Is it because d = GCD(a,b) and that will always be less than a and b?

Comment: Would the statement be true if we stuck with natural numbers?  Keep in mind we're working with integers.

Comment: ^In response to my above comment.... combine this with your assumption "$ax+by>0$.  can you come up with counterexamples if this isn't true?

Comment: No.  $a | (-a)$ and $(-a) | a$.

Answer (score 3):

$d| (ax+by)  $ so that $$ ax+by=dn$$ If $ ax+by >0$, then $$n\neq 0,\ ax+by=|dn| \geq d $$